# Ionic3 serve error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic3

I am still having this problem and is really frustrating. Any can help?

[image]

Ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.2
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v8.7.0
npm               : 2.15.12
OS                : Windows 10
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Does anyone help me?

Comment: Could u share the codes?

Comment: @Dr.Geek : please See picture above

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,                                           
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 15:0-52
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts